# Unable to add more than one custom log in BlueMix Containers

Tags: logging, containers, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I am able to collect one custom log using the LOG_LOCATIONS environment variable w/o problem. When I add a second log (LOG_LOCATIONS=log1,log2,log3...) this appears to break logging and no logs (even default container logs) show up in the logging UI.

In my scenario I'm using the official Liberty Container and trying to pull in the Liberty message and http access logs.

Are there any known problems with the container crawler technology? Is there anything I can do to check that these environment variables are being passed into the crawler properly?

Answer (score 0):

I can successfully add 2 logs when I run an IBM Container using the following command:

```
$ cf ic run --env LOG_LOCATIONS=/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/logs/messages.log,/var/log/bootstrap.log --name ads-liberty -P registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibmliberty
```

I can then go to the Logging tab in the Bluemix UI and see entries from both logs.

Creating the IBM Container via UI also worked:

- I expanded Advanced Options
- I clicked "Add a new environment variable" link
- For key I entered `LOG_LOCATIONS`
- For value I entered `/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/logs/messages.log,/var/log/bootstrap.log`